# Not able to configure SSL with Tomcat 7

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat7

I am trying to configure SSL with Tomcat 7 but not able to do so. Please guide.

## Command for generating SSL certificate:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin>keytool -genkeypair -alias tomcat-keystore -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\my.keystore
```

## server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" 
    keystoreFile="C:\my.keystore" keystorePass="abc" 
    clientAuth="false" keyAlias="tomcat-keystore" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

The problem is that if I put https://wwww.secdevapp.net:8443 the browser says "The webpage is not available" and I see the error in the catalina.log file (mentioned below) but http://www.secdevapp.net:8080 works fine.

## Tomcat Error Log:

```
Mar 26, 2014 11:22:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:813)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Connector attribute SSLCertificateFile must be defined when using SSL with APR
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:467)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commenting out the APR listener in server.xml line:27 does the trick in Windows OS.
Found the solution from http://java.dzone.com/articles/ssl-your-tomcat-7

*The APR is a native library that you may install during Tomcat installation. It does tie your Tomcat to your OS but "provide superior scalability and performance". This is a good thing to do for your production environment. In other environments, I don't see the point.*

Answer (score 0):

- Check the port on your server. Is tomcat/java actually listening on
  port 8443?
- Check the tomcat logs, usually in tomcat/logs directory. What does
  the access log say?
- Did you restart tomcat after using that Connector? What does
  catalina.log say?

Comment: Found some error in the catalina.log as per your direction. Added error log to the original post. Answering your two other questions: Yes, I restarted Tomcat and I checked server.xml and Tomcat is listening on port 8443.